# How to import modules for unit tests with QUnit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I've been trying to add unit tests for some modular ES6 code. I have a project structure like this:

```
project
└───src
|   └───js
|           cumsum.js
|       index.js <--- entry point
└───test
        tests.js <--- QUnit test code
```

This is what's in `cumsum.js`:

```
export const cumsum=x=>{
    var result = x.reduce((r, a)=> {
        if (r.length > 0) {
            a += r[r.length - 1];
        }
        r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);
    return result;
}
```

Now, if I run this sample test by running `qunit` in the command line, it will work:

```
const A=[1,2,3,4,5];
const expected=[1,3,6,10,15];
QUnit.test( "cumsum", function( assert ) {
    assert.deepEqual([1,3,6,10,15],expected);
});
```

but if I try to import the actual `cumsum` function, it doesn't recognize proper ES6 import syntax:

```
import {cumsum} from '../src/js/cumsum';
const A=[1,2,3,4,5];
const expected=[1,3,6,10,15];
QUnit.test( "cumsum", function( assert ) {
    assert.deepEqual(cumsum(A),expected);
});
```

I just get the error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Is there a way to use QUnit with ES6 modules? If not, is there a unit testing framework that will let me test these modules?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've come up with so far.

Chrome can sort of natively run ES6 modules. It's not good enough for web production but it is enough to run some unit tests. So in the `test` folder I have `index.html` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.9.2.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.9.2.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="../src/js/cumsum.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="tests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In `test/tests.js` I have the original test code:

```
import {cumsum} from '../src/js/cumsum';
const A=[1,2,3,4,5];
const expected=[1,3,6,10,15];
QUnit.test( "cumsum", function( assert ) {
    assert.deepEqual(cumsum(A),expected);
});
```

Now, for some reason you can't directly open `test/index.html` in the web browser because although Chrome will happily read ordinary javascript files locally it will break if you set `type="module"` on a local file. Instead we have to launch a web server and view it that way. Any dev server will do, so `webpack-dev-server` works fine. Open `http://localhost:8080/test/` in Chrome and the unit tests load.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this? Node.js uses the same javascript engine as Chrome so in theory I think it should be possible to do this from the command line without launching a web server and opening a browser.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, which is that Chrome doesn't really support ES6 modules natively (fully). Since the qunit CLI uses a headless browser, it's still a browser, and does not support ES6 modules either.

Comment: Thanks. A few years later, this answer is still relevant and clean in my opinion. It saved us quite some time today in our setup of QUnitJs. 